# How to resolve API Mass Assignment in web method having single parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, webforms, penetration-testing

I am working in website project in visual studio 2012. Here I have a web method which is taking single parameter. This method get called from `AutoCompleteExtender` control. Below is the code of it:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" CssClass="form-control setvaluework" MaxLength="4000" />
   <ajx:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtsearch" ServicePath="SearchWebService.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetWorsList"
   MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionSetCount="20" CompletionInterval="0" EnableCaching="true"  CompletionListElementID="autocompleteList" >
</ajx:AutoCompleteExtender>`
```

"GetWorsList" is defined as follows:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public List<string> GetWorsList(string prefixText)
{
    List<string> workNames = null;
    if (Validations.ValidWorkNoAjax(prefixText) == false)
    {
        return workNames;
    }
    else
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = "%" + prefixText + "%";

        /*Some Code*/

        return workNames;
     }
}
```

I am working to protect this method from `API Mass Assignment`. In an audit scan this method gets exploited.When a POST request was made in a test scan following payload was used:

```json
{
 "prefixText": "WL",
 "count": 20,
 "is_admin": true,
 "is_sso": true,
 "role": "admin"
}
```

and it returns 200 OK status, which should not be the case because function is taking only single input as `prefixText`.

I have searched regarding this and found that I have to

> avoid using functions that automatically bind client's input to code variables or internal objects.If applicable, explicitly define and enforce schema's for the input data payloads.

To achieve this I tried following:

```
public object GetWorsList(string prefixText)
{
    var requestStrings = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;

    foreach (var item in requestStrings.AllKeys)
    {
        if (!item.Contains("prefixText") && !item.Contains("count"))
        {
           return BadRequest("Invalid Request");
        }
    }
}
```

I created a whitelist of parameters which will be accepted. If any other parameter is added by the attacker then this method will return the `BadRequest`. But again in a POST request this method is not working i.e. I am not getting `BadRequest`. I tested this in postman using following details:

`http://localhost:6949/ewbms_bb/SearchWebService.asmx/GetWorsList` in POST request
The payload I sent is :

```
{
 "prefixText": "WL",
 "count": 20,
 "is_admin": true,
 "is_sso": true,
 "role": "admin"
}
```

Using the above payload the method should return `BadRequest`, but it is giving status code `200 OK`.

I also tried creating a separate class like this:

```cs
public class WorkSearchModel 
{
    public string prefixText { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and used `WorkSearchModel` as my method parameter. When I test this using postman and also in localhost, I get the error : `There was an error processing the request.`

Through my search on internet, I found that 'API Mass Assignment' is properly handled in Asp.Net Core, but in webform/website project I found no such result. Please give guidance.

Comment: You will need to create a `ModelBinder` that is specific to each view model.  This is a completely ridiculous requirement.  There is no API Mass Assignment issue here.  There aren't any 'hidden' or 'extra' properties that can assigned to this endpoint.  You could supply 1 million extra properties, and it would still work.  I'd push back on the requirement, until whoever said it can prove it's an issue.

Comment: @Neil actually the issue was reported in a Security Report which was created by HCL AppScan Standard 10.2.0. I've no idea about this tool and this was used by some third person out of my reach. Can you please help me(by elaborating the concept) in giving my submission in order to close this issue. How can I explain about "1 million extra properties, and it would still work". On the same ground if you can explain why there is no API Mass Assignment Issue here ? 
Thanks!